# Как в Angular реализовать отмену события blur?

Tags: angular

В родительском компонете в шаблоне которого просто инпут, в дочернем компоненте список который через ngForm итерирует данные которые пришли из родительского компонента. По клику на форму срабатывает событие фокус и список весь отображается, еще есть событие blur которое должно прятать список, если клик произошел не по списку. Вывожу в консоль event.target от блюра и где бы я не кликал получаю свой инпут? Почему так?

Answer (score 0):

Событие blur генерируется инпутом когда тот теряет фокус. Поэтому в event.target и возвращается сам инпут.

Инпут так же может потерять фокус (и сгенерироват событие blur) при потери фокуса, например, окном браузера. Ради интереса попробуйте переключиться с инпута на девелоперскую консоль. Увидите что blur тоже сработал, но ни один фактический элемент на странице (кроме самого инпута, потерявшего фокус) не участвовал в этом.